# Extra Line read from file

Tags: c

I'm trying to read from a text file and store it into an array, but my last array is filled with garbage, is there any way to fix it? For reference, I don't need that last line of values, but I can't seem to find a way to get rid of it.

```
int k;
char string[100];
for(k = 0; k < MAX_STATIONS; k++){
    if (fgets(string, sizeof(string), fp) == 0){
        break;
    }
    fscanf(fp,"%d %f %d %d %d %d %d %f %f", &stationInfo[k].stationID, &stationInfo[k].temperature, &stationInfo[k].year, &stationInfo[k].month, &stationInfo[k].day, &stationInfo[k].hour, &stationInfo[k].minute, &stationInfo[k].location.latitude, &stationInfo[k].location.longitude);
    printf("%d %1.2f %d %d %d %d %d %f %f\n", stationInfo[k].stationID, stationInfo[k].temperature, stationInfo[k].year, stationInfo[k].month, stationInfo[k].day, stationInfo[k].hour, stationInfo[k].minute, stationInfo[k].location.latitude, stationInfo[k].location.longitude);
}
```

EDIT: I've realized that using this method, I don't actually get the first line of my file read. How could I fix this?

Comment: *"For reference, I don't need that last line of values, but I can't seem to find a way to get rid of it."* - Then why do you care?  Your array values are probably just uninitialized, you can't read a line that's not there.  if the number of lines is less than the number of array elements then yeah, your last N elements will be junk.  How about showing us a (reduced) set of input?  My bet is that `MAX_STATIONS` is > the number of lines in the file.

Comment: `fscanf` is an extraordinarily fragile way to read and parse file content. And you are compounding the issue by not even testing the return value it provides which would tell you how many of its fields it successfully parsed.

Comment: Yes, the number of lines in the file is < MAX_STATIONS, but I doesn't my fgets statement cover my basis for detecting garbage here? Here is the file I'm trying to read: http://pastebin.com/LJzLT8GH

Comment: @JakeCooper: You have an array with a bunch of (probably) uninitialized structures.  If you don't initialize them all in your loop then of course some at the end will remain uninitialized ("garbage").  Your if statements checks for success on `fgets`, but you still have more array elements than lines

Comment: **Dat line!** is 280 characters long. That should raise the red flag: you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Ed S: Got it, would it be better to write a function to count the number of lines in the file, then initialize an array accordingly?

@H2CO3 Ya, Sorry, ATM just trying to get it to work, I'll make it pretty after I get it working :).

Comment: I have since fixed my garbage problem (Thanks Ed S). But, my program does not read my first file (it didn't in the first place). How can I fix this?

Comment: Just to be sure: you're reading a file 2 lines at a time. The first of each set is a string of characters, the second is 9 numbers. Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 2):

You should check the return value of [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/)  it returns the number of read fields and ignore (or print a warning) lines which are incomplete. Another idea would be to check whether 100 chars are really long enough to hold the longest line (+ EOS).